# Can I have one XML in drawable folder supporting multiple colors/borders for multiple button?

Tags: android, button, shapes, xml-drawable

I have 2 buttons with two different colors and border colors. So I need to create a XML in drawable folder with shape attribute and:

```
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#C5510E" />

<solid android:color="#F78340" />`
```

and another XML with:

```
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<solid android:color="#000000" />
```

Is there a way where I can handle them in one XML inside drawable folder rather than two XML?

Comment: It is not possible. Although the answer on this post  might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630206/defining-xml-parent-style-of-gradient-shape-corners

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Unlike other components, `drawable` resources are not given IDs, so they are referenced only by part filename through `R.drawable`. They must be handled in separate files.

See developer documentation on [referencing a `shape` `drawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape). (Other `drawable` types are on that same bit of documentation, if interested.)